# Inverse of this piecewise-defined function

Tags: matlab, math, gaussian, inverse, piecewise

I would need to implement the inverse function of the following piecewise-defined function through MATLAB:

[image]

which is an approximation for Gaussian function.

I have already tried using `finverse` function for each separate piecewise function, however the results (`0` and `NaN`) don't seem to match my expectations.

`x` is a value to be substituted by a number, so I think it would be fair enough to have my answer in **numerical form**, as I don't think it is exactly invertible in the symbolic one -if it is possible then I think it would be better to do it in a symbolic way.

Could you please give me a hand with this?

**Edit on 12/05/2017**

Here you can see my initial attempt:

```
    Q_1 = exp(-0.4527*x^0.86 + 0.0218);
    Q_2 = sqrt(pi/x)*exp(-x/4)*(1-20/(7*x));

    b = 1-(1-lambda)^(j-1);
    if b < 10, r_idle(j) = subs(finverse(Q_1,x),x,b);
    else,      r_idle(j) = subs(finverse(Q_2,x),x,b);
```

`j` is just an integer (these are results are parameters of a vector) and `lambda` just a real number calculated beforehand. For instance, `0.4065`.

Comment: do you want the answer in symbolic or numerical form?

Comment: If you are interested in the numerical inverse, you can use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690225/invert-a-series-of-data-as-if-inverting-a-function-using-matlab/43695274#43695274).

Comment: Sorry for your answers @freude I am editing the question!

Comment: @m7913d Thank you for your answer! But what if I have a single value for x and I just want to obtain the corresponding inverse function?

Comment: If `y = phi(x)`, then `x = phi^-1(y)`. If you evaluate your function only in one point, you cannot inverse your function numerically in more points. So, why do you not evaluate your function in more points? For example a linearly spaced vector `linspace(x1,x2)`, between your points of interest `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing the inverse of function in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083078/computing-the-inverse-of-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [Computing the inverse of function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083078/computing-the-inverse-of-function-in-matlab), but the piece-wise part makes it a bit different.

Note: The function is not continuous at 10, , with a jump of 0.006 - is that OK?

[image]

1. First you need to reverse the limits, this can be done analytically by noting both are monotonic decreasing functions, so the first image (call it g) has a maximum at `0` and a minimum at 10, and similarly for the second image (call it h):

   x<10 -> g(10)=0.038476 < g(x) < 1.02204=g(0)

   x>=10-> 0 < h(x)<0.0328633

Note anything between 0.0328633 and 0.038476 is undefined, as is everything above 1.02204, and 0 and below.

2. The second part is to actually inverse the functions. `g` is trivial and is simply given by:

   x=(1/0.4527*(0.0218-log(g))^(1/0.86)

The math:

[image]

You can compute this straight forwardly, like a normal function. (given g, get x).

3. `h` (the second part of your function) is not analytically reversible.
   Use the solution to the question I linked to at the top to reverse it (remember, only in the limits 0 < h(x) < 0.0328633).

Comment: The jump is positive in the graph when it should be negative from the values you gave.

Comment: @G.J Thanks, I made a mistake in the plot.

Comment: Hello @kabanus, 


Thanks a lot for your answer. How did you obtain the first inverse? I tried to do it through 'finverse' function, but I was given 0 as a result. I'm attaching what I tried in my original post. BR!!

Comment: @MisterTellini Pen and paper. See edit. finverse can't work for everything, the problem is the bounds. Use the link for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is convenient to make use of indicator (logical) functions and use the `interp1` function.

```
phi=@(x) exp(-0.4527*(x.^0.86)+0.0218).*(x < 10)...
    + sqrt(pi./x).*exp(-x./4).*(1-(20./(7*x))).*(x >= 10)

X = (.01:.01:20)';
```

Then `interp1(phi(X),X,xq)` gives the inverse.

```
>> interp1(phi(X),X,[0.01 0.05 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1])
ans =
   14.4851    9.0773    6.7013    4.4395    3.1844    2.3332    1.7013    1.2081    0.8120    0.4896    0.2284    0.0294
```

[image]